# How do you tell the amount of solution of this row reduced matrix?

Tags: matrices

The first four correspond to the variables x, y, z and u and the fifth column corresponds to the right-sides.

**The thing i'm asking is, how many solutions does this system of questions have and how do you find that out?** Not sure how to think of it because there's no "Free variable"

[image]

Comment: (1) This is not a Mathematica question. (2) Dimension of solution space = #vars - #pivots.

Answer (score 0):

Write down the equations and you get:
$$
x+\frac{88}{87}u=\frac5{29}\\
y+\frac{317}{87}u=\frac{77}{29}\\
z-\frac{184}{87}u=-\frac{21}{29}
$$
You see that you can easily get a solution depending on $u$ and $u$ is a free variable:
$$
x=\frac5{29}-\frac{88}{87}u\\
y=\frac{77}{29}-\frac{317}{87}u\\
z=-\frac{21}{29}+\frac{184}{87}u
$$